# Data format issue in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I'm trying to implement `vue-chart-js` in my `VueJS 2.0` application, I went through the documentation and I'm using the component like:

```
<div class="row">
    <vue-chart type="bar" :options="options" :data="chartData" style="width: 100%;height: 310px;"></vue-chart>
</div>
```

In `data()` I'm defining:

```
//for chart
options: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            //stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            //stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                barPercentage: 0.2,
                autoSkip: false,
            },
        }]
    },
```

I did some static data set to get my chart working so my `chartData` looks like this:

```
if(type==="week"){
    this.chartData.labels=['1st Week', '2nd Week', '3rd Week', '4th Week', '5th Week', '6th Week']
    this.chartData.datasets= [
        {
            label:'Investor',
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            backgroundColor: "rgb(26, 179, 148)",
            borderColor: "rgba(26, 179, 148,1)",
        },
        {
            label:'Research',
            data: [50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10],
            backgroundColor: "rgb(138, 209, 194)",
            borderColor: "rgba(26, 179, 148,1)",
        },

    ]
}
else if(type==="month"){
    this.chartData.labels=['1st Month', '2nd Month', '3rd Month', '4th Month', '5th Month', '6th Month']
    this.chartData.datasets= [
        {
            label:'Investor',
            data: [90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 100, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            backgroundColor: "rgb(26, 179, 148)",
            borderColor: "rgba(26, 179, 148,1)",
        },
        {
            label:'Research',
            data: [50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10],
            backgroundColor: "rgb(138, 209, 194)",
            borderColor: "rgba(26, 179, 148,1)",
        },

    ]
}
```

Now I pointed the same to the api calls so I did something like this:

```
axios.get('api/interaction/chart?timeFormat='+type, {headers: getHeader()}).then(response => {
    if(response.status === 200)
    {
        this.chartData = response.data.chartData
        console.log(this.chartData)
    }
})
```

In response or in `console.log` I'm having the format something like this:

```
{
    "labels":["1st Week","2nd Week","3rd Week","4th Week","5th Week","6th Week"],
    "datasets":[
        {"label":"Investor","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"backgroundColor":"rgb(26, 179, 148)","borderColor":"rgb(26, 179, 148,1)"},
        {"label":"Research","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0],"backgroundColor":"rgb(138, 209, 194)","borderColor":"rgb(26, 179, 148,1)"}
    ]
}
```

I'm getting an error of:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, Array, got String.
>   found in---> `<VueChart>`

I tried using `JSON.parse(response.data.chartData)` but this also not helping me out. Guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: `if(type==="week")`  ?? why `===`

Comment: How do you pass data to your chart? Can you provide template and data object structure?

Comment: @ElDanielo I've updated the question, please check.

Comment: Not sure if this directly relates to your issue, but technically this should not properly set `this.chartData`. Inside of your callback, `this` would be referring to the axios request. You'll need `this` from your vue instance / component.

Try to do `var self = this` before you make your axios call, then set chartData using `self.chartData = response.data.chartData`

If chartData's intial value is set to a string and it doesn't get set in your callback... that could explain your issue.